# How to print only characters from list in python

Tags: python, list

I am working on a script to print only the alphabets in the list.

```
test = ['a',1,'b',2]
for i in test:
    if i.isalpha() == True:
        print(i)
```

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha'

How can I print only the character values from the given list?

Comment: try str(i).isalpha() instead

Comment: You can only use `.isalpha()` on a string. So: `if str(i).isalpha():` . There is no need for `== True`.

Comment: Its working !! :)  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution

```
test = ['a',1,'b',2,None]
for i in test:
    if i is not None and str(i).isalpha():
        print(i)
```

Edit after response Rolv Apneseth

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
test = ["a", 1, "b", 2]
for char in test:
    if isinstance(char, str) and char.isalpha():
        print(char)
```

---

Note that only strings have the `.isalpha()` method, so I checked for type but you could alternatively just use `str(char).isalpha()`. However, that would mean values such as `None` would also be included in the output which I'm assuming you do not want.

Also as [@BoarGules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084384/boargules) pointed out, you don't need the `== True`.

Comment: Instead of using `type` I'd suggest using `isinstance(i, str)`

Comment: My comment didn't post yesterday for some reason but yes thank you for the suggestion I don't know why I didn't do that in the first place

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a more Pythonic way.

```py
print('\n'.join(c for c in ['a',1,'b',2] if str(c).isalpha()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer to your question:

```
test = ['a',1,'b',2]
for i in test:
    if str(i).isalpha() == True:
        print(i)
```